# How to Display User Avatar With User's Name and Chat Message?

Tags: javascript, meteor, avatar

I'm working on an instant messaging assignment. Instructions are: "Adapt the templates and helper functions so the messaging window displays users’ avatars next to their messages." There are a few similar questions on stackoverflow, and I've tried to implement the answers, but none worked for me. I have user name, but the avatar only displays the avatar of the user that is logged in. In this example, user2 avatar should display with user2 message.[image: display avatar]

**Template**

```
<template name="chat_message">
<img src="/{{avatar}}" class="chat_img" />
    <span class="text">On {{timeStamp}}</span> <span class="text">{{getUserById sentBy}}</span> said: {{text}}
    <br>
    <br>
</template>
```

**Client**

```
Template.chat_message.helpers({
  avatar:function(){
    return Meteor.user().profile.avatar;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.user() returns the user record of the *current user*.

What you need is the user record of the user who sent the message.

It looks like you already have a "getUserById" helper which returns the userid of the user - do a similar thing to get the avatar of the user

Comment: I'll say the same as I did above. Thanks for your reply and explaining the reasoning. It helps greatly. As I was telling the other commenter, this is my first class doing any kind of coding. I'm stunned I even made it this far. Thank you for taking the time to give direction with a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the avatar of `Meteor.user()` which is the current logged-in user not the user creating the message.

I see that you already have a helper named `getUserById` to get the user creating the message. Base on that you should be able to create a helper to get the correct avatar.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply and your comment makes perfect sense. I will follow that line of reasoning. I'm a designer, not a coder, and usually rely on cutting and pasting free bits of code and packages and not always able to reason this stuff as well as you did here.